# Hypersurface $S\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ whose intersection with $Z(xy-zw)$ is a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry

> Let $X=Z(xy-zw)\subset\mathbb{P}^3$. Prove that there is no hypersurface $S\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ such that the intersection of $X$ and $S$ is a line.

My initial idea was to restrict $X$ by an affine map supposing $w=1$, i.e., considering $X=Z(z-xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^3$ and $S=Z(f)$ for some irreducible $f$. If the intersection is a line $Z(l_1, l_2)$ for linear polynomials $l_1,l_2$, then $<f, z-xy>=<l_1,l_2>$, which seems absurd, but I'm not being able to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some steps, where I leave some details for you to check. Assume $F=0$ intersected $X$ in a line $L$ given by linear equations, $l_1=l_2=0$. Then, in particular, we have $xy-zw=q_1l_1+q_2l_2$, for some linear polynomials $q_i$s. Show that $l_i, q_i$ have no common zeroes (essentially due to smoothness of $X$) and thus the line $M$ given  by $q_1=q_2=0$ is disjoint from $L$. Now, $F=0$ intersects $X$ precisely in $L$ implies $F=0$ can not intersect $M$ at all. But, every line intersects every hypersurface, leading to a contradiction. Notice that we showed that there is no such hypersurface meeting $X$ in $L$ even set-theoretically, not  ideal theoretically. Another note: the argument comes from intersection theory. Any line in $X$ has self-intersection zero, but any hypersurface intersection is ample and thus has self-intersection positive.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Dear Georges, no, the line is still defined by $l_i=0$ and contained in $X$, so $xy-zw\in (l_1,l_2)$. This does not mean $(F,xy-zw)=(l_1,l_2)$, but, they are same upto radicals.

Comment: Dear Mohan, yes you are right. I apologize for my erroneous comment, which I have now deleted.